# When passing user input from one jsp to another jsp i encounter an Exception on executeQuery()

Tags: oracle, apache, jsp, exception, web-applications

I am trying to run a web app on ApacheTomcat. I want to send a name(from index.jsp) to action.jsp and on that basis i wan to run a query and display the result on the webpage(action.jsp). In the line containing executeQuery() i am getting an exception.

I don't think the query is the problem since it runs fine on SQL developer.
I am using Oracle 11g,Eclipse.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <%
    String fname=request.getParameter("fname");
    String lname=request.getParameter("lname");
        Connection con=null;
        PreparedStatement ps=null;

            try
            {
                String q="select id,(firstname||' '||lastname) as name from employee_vm where firstname="+fname+" and lastname="+lname;
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "system", "1234");
                ps=con.prepareStatement(q);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                out.println(e);
            }

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(); 
        out.println("<table border=1 >");
        out.println("<tr style='background-color:#ffffb3; color:red'>");
        out.println("<th>Emp Id</th>");
        out.println("<th>Name(Year)</th>");
        //out.println("<th>Linemanager Id</th>");
        //out.println("<th>Manager Name</th>");
        //out.println("<th>Level</th>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        while(rs.next())
        {
            out.println("<tr style='background-color:#b3ffd9;'>");
            out.println("<td>"+rs.getInt(1)+"</td>");
            out.println("<td>"+rs.getString(2)+"</td>");
           // out.println("<td>"+rs.getInt(3)+"</td>");
           // out.println("<td>"+rs.getString(4)+"</td");
            //out.println("<td>"+rs.getInt(5)+"</td>");
            out.println("</tr>");
        }
```

Comment: There are a lot of things you need to learn. 1. Read the message and stack trace of the exception. It tells you what and where the problem is. 2. Don't put Java code in JSPs. Put the Java code in Java classes. Use JSPs to generate HTML from the model stored in request attributes by a controller servlet, using only JSP tags and the JSP EL. 3. Learn to use prepared statements. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and will fail as soon as one of the parameters contains a quote. 4. Don't generate HTML from Java code. That's precisely the role of a JSP.

Comment: 5. Don"t catch Exception. Catching and ignoring (or just printing the exception) is what prevents you from being able to know what the problem is. And it catches exceptions that should never be caught. 6. Don't get the connection from DriverManager. Use a DataSource, which gets connection out of a connection pool. 7. Use the try-with-resources statement to make sure your connection is always closed properly.

Comment: Regarding your precise question, as I said before, without being able to read the message and stack trace of the exception, and without knowing the values of the parameters, we can only guess. I this case, my educated guess is that since you're not using prepared statements, you forgot to add quotes around your parameters. Another bug that prepared statements allow avoiding. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html